# Why did David Budd lie about Andy Apsted?

Tags: plot-explanation, bodyguard

In the UK TV series [*Bodyguard* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7493974/), David Budd lies about not knowing Andy Apsted.

The truth was simply that Budd knew Apsted from his days in Afghanistan and he was completely surprised to find him on the rooftop.

So, why didn't Budd simply tell the truth? Instead he lied; why? (Clearly, it would only be a matter of time before his Afghanistan connection to Apsted was discovered and his lie uncovered.)

---

In S01E06, Budd says:

> Louise, I know I betrayed your trust.
>
> I lied about Andy Apsted.
>
> But if I'd come clean, I'd have been the fall guy and the people that really killed Julia would have gotten away with it.

I don't understand the explanation given in this last sentence. Why would Budd have been the fall guy if he'd simply told the truth?

Sure, they might have investigated him a little. But they would have found nothing, because there was nothing to find. By lying, wouldn't he be far more of a fall guy when his lie was eventually uncovered?

Answer (score 2):

He lied to buy himself more time and be able to work so have access to data and information. Something we see is crippled when he is suspended and need to beg police to let him work together.

Budd knew that if he comes clean then he will be A) blamed for being a collaborator to Apsted OR/AND B) suspended for connection and to not meddle with the investigation OR/AND C) be immediately arrested .

He also concluded that Apsted was supplied by someone and that someone was behind the attempts and that they were quite powerful. He concluded that him and Apsted would be perfect scapegoats.

Comment: 2 people don't like  this answer, but aren't writing a better one.